# NSDateFormatter not giving consitent date according to region

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I trying to localize my date, but for some reason some the it doesn't also output the correct format from regions.

This is how it test my code:

```
if(dateformater==nil)
dateformater =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformater setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateformater setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateformater setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString  *string_date=[dateformater stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Loacle:----%@   Date:----%@",[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier],string_date);
```

Here are some examples of what the localized dates look like and where is goes wrong.

```
Loacle:----da_DK   Date:----24/11/2011 14.10--------(WRONG)
Loacle:----en_BE   Date:----24 Nov 2011 14:09--------(OK)
Loacle:----nl_BE   Date:----24-nov.-2011 14:10------(WRONG)
Loacle:----fr_BE   Date:----24 nov. 2011 14:11-------(OK)
Loacle:----en_US   Date:----Nov 24, 2011 2:11 PM-----(OK)
Loacle:----en_GB   Date:----24 Nov 2011 14:11--------(OK)
```

The requirements state that it should consistent for all regions.

Comment: Explain why the "WRONG" lines are wrong.

Comment: I want consistent means for loacale en_BE i am not getting separators and getting month symbol but da_DK i am getting separators in date and i am getting 11 instead of Nov

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same output, you need to use the same locale, or use `setDateFormat:`.  The whole point of having locales is to have *different* formats for different styles.

Comment: i don't want same output ,i need date according to the locale.

Comment: Perhaps you need to look at using `setDateFormat:` instead of `setDateStyle:` and `setTimeStyle:`.

Comment: if i set specific format i will get more problems .as locale en_US we are getting Nov 24, 2011 2:11 PM and for locale en_GB we are getting 24 Nov 2011 14:11. order of date and month may be change